# Progress Bar Problem in Android

Tags: android, progress-bar

My app contained download button and whenever that button is pressed, I want some Progress Bar to show up so that the user knows there is something happening. What I really want to do is, whenever the Progress Bar is finished, I want some Toast to pop out. Can some one guide me with this? I would really appreciate it a lot. Thanks in advance!

Here is the code I am using:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMessage("Downloading...");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMax(200);
        dialog.setProgress(0);
        dialog.show();

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                while(dialog.getProgress() < dialog.getMax())
                {
                    dialog.incrementProgressBy(1);
                    try{Thread.sleep(50);}catch(Exception e){/* no-op */}
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: what you are getting now.where is your problem,in progress bar or in showing Toast or in both

Comment: My progress bar is fine, but I want some Toast to pop out when the progress bar is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask would be the easiest but if you are adamant on using your code you can add this snippet after the dialog.dismiss() statement.

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(YourClassName.this, "task finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }

  });
```

This is because the Toast must only be shown on the UI Thread.

Comment: Thanks dude, this is exactly what I am looking for. I am trying it right now!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using AsyncTask in android. 
Here are few links which will be handy.

http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/asynctasks-with-progressdialogs

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/asynctask_progressdialog.aspx

http://javatech.org/2011/02/discovering-android-opening-a-progress-dialog-with-asynctask/

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-download-files-with-progress-dialog/

Answer (score 0):

After dialog.dismiss(); write

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"finish",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: The problem is doing UI activity outside UI thread.You can override progress dialog onStop method and can write the Toast or alert Dialog there

Comment: better to use AsyncTask as Andro_Selva said

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run long tasks on UI thread. Create a background thread with Async Task but you cannot do a toast in a background thread.

Async task will notify when the task is complete.

I think Async task has the following methods.

onBackground
onProgressUpdate
PreExecute
PostExecute (put a toast here)